# Check active grails plugins

Tags: grails, plugins

Is there a way to check which Grails plugins are active and used durring application runtime?
I want to remove a plugin but I want to be absolutely sure that it is not used anymore...

Comment: How do you define "active"? How is it different from "used"?

Comment: @dmahapatro Hey dude :-) I think that he want's to know if some Grails artefact from his app is using the plugin before removing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, a brute force way would be to copy your Grails project (preferably using a source control tool like git's branching feature), remove the plugin, and make sure that:

1. No exceptions on a `grails clean`, `grails compile`, and `grails refresh-dependencies`.
2. All unit and integration tests pass (your team is writing those, right? ;) )
3. You can run the application and use it fairly normally; warning, this is the worst test, and by itself isn't sufficient, as you could end up with a [BOMM](http://www.buildsonmymachine.com/).

If you're familiar with the classes in the plugin, but there are way too many Grails files to look through manually, you could use code search tools like [those found in GGTS](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/searching-for-text-in-eclipse.html) whatever IDE/text editor you're using. Even [grep](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep) could be handy for finding references to those classes or some distinctly named methods.

Conversely, if the plugin is basically a black box, and your Grails app is small enough to get around, check the import statements at the top of your Controllers, Domains, and Services. If the plugin provides more client-side technology (like the jQuery plugin) check your GSPs and various items in the web-app directory (like Javascript files) for references to it.